# XPathで要素の存在を確認する方法

Tags: python, selenium

python2.7.10とseleniumとchrome driverです。

pythonでseleniumを使って、xpathを用いてfind_elementする際、そのxpathの要素が存在するかどうかで処理を分けたいのですが、どう記述すべきでしょうか。

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="rank"]/tbody/tr[2]/td[1]').text
```

if文で分岐したいのですが、if文内でそんな要素ない！ってエラー吐かれてしまい・・・。

ご存知の方がいれば、教えて下さい。

Comment: 私が`ruby`で同様の問題にあたったときは例外処理で対処していました。Pythonがわからないため具体的なコードは示せないのですが…。

Comment: ありがとうございます！例外処理でいけそうです！

Answer (score 1):

find_elementsを使います。返り値の型はリストで、対応する要素が無ければ空のリストになるだけです。

Comment: ありがとうございます！　確かに空のリストが返ってきましたので、これで存在確認できそうです。

Answer (score 0):

Pythonでは例外処理を`try`と`except`で行います。
条件式や関数と同様に「:」とインデントを使って記述します。

```
try:
    # 要素がある場合の処理
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="rank"]/tbody/tr[2]/td[1]').text
except:
    # 要素がない場合の処理（※正確にはtryの内容を実行してエラーが起こる場合の処理）
    ここに記述
```

Comment: ありがとうございます！　例外処理が良さそうですので、こちらで実装してみます！！

Comment: 良かったです！　スクレイピングでは各処理ごとに例外処理を実装し、except内にprintを置きどこでつまづいたかを吐くようにしておくと便利です。